# Работа с двумя таблицами php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы, продажа и склад. В обоих таблицах есть столбец koll (количество)
нужно каким то образом вычесть количество продаж из количества на склад. При этом так нужно сделать во всех совпадающих полях по имени.
Имена индивидуальные (повторений нет)

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (w.koll - s.koll) AS diff
FROM warehouse AS w
LEFT JOIN sale AS s ON s.name = w.name
```

Comment: Можно пояснение к этому запросу? или лучше даже на примере)

Comment: При использовании вашего sql запроса и при выводи его на экран выводится вот что: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 10 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )